# Image Data Generator for images in Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

So I have my images in a numpy array but not in a directory. I have a final numpy array which is a 4d tensor of shape (sample, 48, 48, 1). My goal is to use keras's image data generator to convert them to (sample, 224, 224, 1). Please guide me on how to do it as so far I have seen examples of people using image data generators from the directory where they load actuall images.

I have 4 numpy arrays stored localy `train_images.npy`, `train_labels.npy`, `test_images.npy` and `test_labels.npy`.

The shape for images in these numpy is `(sample, 48, 48, 1)`
The shape for labels in these numpy is `(sample, number of classes)` as i have already converted them to `keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical` method.

Comment: could you include any code you have already tried? why cant you save your images to a directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this you should use [`ImageDataGenerator.flow`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow), which takes `numpy` arrays directly. This replaces the `flow_from_directory` call, all other code using the generator should be the same.

Comment: Amazing. Worked like a charm.